# Sharing data from a VueJS component

Tags: vue.js

I have a VueJS address lookup component.

```
Vue.component('address-lookup',
{
    template: '#address-lookup-template',
    data: function()
    {
        return {
            address: {'name': '', 'town:': '', 'postcode': ''},
            errors: {'name': false, 'town': false, 'postcode': false},
            states: {'busy': false, 'found': false},
            result: {}
        }
    },
    methods:
    {
        findAddress: function(event)
        {
            if( typeof event === 'object' && typeof event.target === 'object' )
            {
                event.target.blur();
            }

            $.ajax(
            {
                context: this,
                url: '/lookup',
                data:
                {
                    'name':     this.address.name,
                    'town':     this.address.town,
                    'postcode': this.address.postcode
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    this.states.busy = false;
                    this.states.found = true;
                    this.address.name = data.name;
                    this.result = data;
                }
            });
        },
        reset: function()
        {
            this.states.found = false;
            this.result = {};
        }
    }
});
```

Inside my template I've then bound the result like so:

```
<p>{{ result.formatted_address }}</p>
```

There is some extra data returned within the result (like a twitter handle) that isn't part of the address lookup template, and occurs on a separate part of the form. For reasons relating to how my form is structured I can't include these inputs within the same template.

I found a way to bind those inputs, although it felt somewhat 'hacky'.

```
<input type="text" name="twitter" v-model="$refs.lookupResult._data.result.twitter">
```

That all works fine.

My problem is that the form is included as part of a larger template sometimes in the context of creating a new record, sometimes in the context of editing. When editing a record, the lookup component is removed (using an `if` server-side, so the template is no longer loaded at all) and when that happens I get this error.

```
$refs.lookupResult._data.result.twitter": TypeError: Cannot read property '_data' of undefined
```

This makes sense. `lookupResult` is defined when I include the template, and when editing I am removing this line:

```
<address-lookup v-ref:lookup-result></address-lookup>
```

I've worked around it by including a version of each extra input without the `v-model` attribute, again using a server-side `if`. But there are quite a few of these and it's getting a bit messy.

Is there a cleaner approach I could be using to better achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know the hierarchy of your layout, it isn't indicated above, but assuming that address-lookup component is a child of your parent, and you in fact need the results of address lookup in that parent, eg:

```
<parent-component> <!-- where you need the data -->
  <address-lookup></address-lookup> <!-- where you lookup the data -->
</parent-component>
```

then you can simply pass the data props, either top-down only (default) or bidirectionally by defining 'address' for example on your parent's vue data hook:

```
// parent's data() function
data = function () { 
  return { 
    address: {} 
  }
}

// parent template, passed address with .sync modifier (to make it bi-directional)
<parent-component>
  <address-lookup :address.sync='address'></address-lookup>
</parent-component>

// have the props accepted in the address look up component
var addressComponent = Vue.extend({
  props: ['address']
})
```

Now in your $.ajax success function, simply set the props you need on `this.address`. Of course you can do this with all the props you need: errors, results, state etc. Even better, if you can nest them into a single key on the parent, you can pass the single key for the object containing all four elements instead of all four separately.

Comment: I don't actually have a parent component. The parent is just the root of the app. But presumably I could make the same connection using the root data? I was trying to avoid having it always defined because it seemed unnecessary as the component is only used on 1 form out of several other pages all using the same VueJS code.

Comment: Yes, the same concept applies, just replace my `parent-component` with the root of your app, the root is a valid parent just like any other.